# Who decides which levels of log message to be printed in destination in logback?

Tags: logging, logback

I have some doubts regarding levels of log messages. I know there are different type of logging level and when to use what. But the thing that i don't understand is who decides  which levels of log message to be printed in destination in Logback?

Is it Logger itself or appenders ?

By logger itself i mean if i set the logger logging level to warning then logger won't pass levels less then warning (info,trace,debug) messages to appenders or  is it the responsibility of appenders to drop message with level less then warning to destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a level on a Logger not on an Appender. Here are some examples from Logback's XML configuration:

```
<logger name="com.foo.bar" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="com.foo.bas" level="WARN"/>
```

In these examples:

- Any Loggers belonging to the namespace: `com.foo.bar` will be subject to the `INFO` level
- Any Loggers belonging to the namespace: `com.foo.bas` will be subject to the `WARN` level

Logback's `rootLogger` defines the default level, the following configuration tells Logback to apply the `INFO` level to all loggers except for those loggers which are explicitly configured using a `<logger/>` declaration:

```
<root level="INFO">          
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

More details [in the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#loggerElement).

To answer this specific question:

> By logger itself i mean if i set the logger logging level to warning then logger won't pass levels less then warning (info,trace,debug) messages to appenders or is it the responsibility of appenders to drop message with level less then warning to destination?

If your Logger is created for a class in the namepsace: `com.x.y` and you have defined a `<logger name="com.x.y" level="INFO"/>` then the **Logger** will filter out any `logger.debug()` invocations since the `DEBUG` level is lower than the `INFO` level.

Comment: so it mean logger won't pass messages with level DEBUG to appender . It will filter them out.Am i understanding right?

Comment: @Prashank Yes, that's correct the `Logger` will discard the log event rather than passing it on to the `Appender`. If you have a look at Logback's `Logger` class you'll see this _if_ statement: `if (effectiveLevelInt > level.levelInt) { return; }` inside each of its `filterAndLogXXX` methods.